# Twitter not working on HybridAuth

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

I have uploaded the website on pantheon. Users aren't able to login by using twitter provider on my website. I'm using the [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module. When I try to login, it shows this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class OAuthException in /srv/bindings/6349f4db8cd54067ae94453f36acb8ec/code/sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php on line 11

How do I fix this issue? I have a Facebook login as well and it works. And both the logins work on local host.

Comment: What is in all your error logs? Server's one? Drupal's watchdog? Browser's console?

Comment: Either that's a bug in hybrid auth, or a problem in your configuration, (such as libraries being included twice). In either case, it's not really on-topic here.

Comment: @Letharion actually problem with configuration may be on topic - if only OP will provide needed data to really answer it. Like error messages and his configuration (except sensitive data of course).

Comment: @Mołot We do have the error message though, don't we? A class is declared twice, and my first guess would be that the files are installed twice, and libraries, or some other method, includes them twice.

Comment: @Letharion i think I commented on cached, pre-edit version, sorry. Yes, it looks like bug in HybridAuth module now.

Comment: @Mołot I deleted the exception class from the OAuth.php files. Its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it, I removed the OAuthException class from the OAuth.php file which can be found in `sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php` and twitter login started working.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the HybridAuth library to the latest version

Comment: I have the latest version (2.2)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue. In your Twitter App settings, make sure you specify the Callback URL. Should be http://YOUR_URL/hybridauth/endpoint